# why viewDidLoad get called after dismissing UIIMagePickerViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating a application in which I am calling webservice in `viewDidLoad` method. the response will populate my form. There is a button that button allow user to capture a image. For that I used `UIImagePickerViewController`. After capturing the image when I dismiss the camara view some time the application enter in `viewWillAppear`. I don't have any issue with this. But Some time this enter in `viewDidLoad` method.

Thats why my form get repopulated.

I don't know what happening Why app is entering in viewDidLoad method?

Any idea plz

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the sequence of events a bit more? When is this some time that `viewDidLoad` is called?

Comment: `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` In this method I am dismissing the Picker. At this point some times it calls `viewDidLoad` then `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the UIImagePickerViewController, often times the camera will cause a memory warning and your viewcontroller's viewDidUnload method will be called.  Next time your view is shown (when the UIImagePickerViewController is dismissed), the viewDidLoad method will be called because it was previously unloaded.

Comment: Yes you are right. this is exactly what happening... How can I prevent this to happen.?

Comment: You can recreate anything that was removed in viewDidUnload, or you can check to see if it is already created in viewDidLoad, and not do it again.

Comment: I am facing this issue in swift, and viewdidunload has been marked unavailable. :\(